# StaggeredGridView cannot scroll up

Tags: android, scroll, html-table

I'm using StaggeredGridView at link https://github.com/maurycyw/StaggeredGridView

I get a problem is:
When I set LayoutParams span for convertView(in adapter getView) StaggeredGridView cannot scroll up.

Here is code in getView of Adapter

```
    case 0:                             
         convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.element_item_tiny, parent,false); 
         params = new LayoutParams(convertView.getLayoutParams());
         params.span = 2;
         convertView.setLayoutParams(params);
         break;            
   default:
         convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.element_item, parent,false);
         params = new LayoutParams(convertView.getLayoutParams());
         params.span = 2;
         convertView.setLayoutParams(params);
         break;
```

Any ideal for that?

Thanks all.

Comment: Show what changes you have done ?

Comment: I've updated questiion

Comment: Did you found the solution? I have facing the same problem.